# Playing mp3 in URL (swift2)

Tags: ios, url, swift2, mp3, xcode7

I want to build a program that reads a certain code (ex: deb_prel), and if the

```
url = "http://www.piano-midi.de/mp3/BFFCEDC41B391847DAE02F6A5EA1E1A8/" +code.text! +".mp3"
```

exists, plays after the search button is clicked, and with a play/pause and adjust volume.

I have already built the storyboard (easy part), but I am having difficulties to build this simple program. I don't known where to begin, can anyone help me?

Comment: i'm using swift 2, xcode 7 beta

Comment: It is not clear from the question what you are trying to achieve, can you edit the question to explain it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to dig deep in `AVFoundation` [here](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/) and  `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/index.html). Also check [this](https://github.com/saqibomer/gigglymic/blob/master/GigglyMic/RecorderViewController.swift) as reference for playing/pausing and recording audio files.

Comment: You need to explain a bit more what issue you are having? Some kind of crash log or errors in question. Based on your question it is really hard to pin point the issue.

Comment: Well, im really new in programming. For instance, i want to play an mp3 audio that exists in an URL. (ex:http://www.piano-midi.de/mp3/BFFCEDC41B391847DAE02F6A5EA1E1A8/deb_pass.mp3) .

Comment: {
let a = "http://www.piano-midi.de/mp3/BFFCEDC41B391847DAE02F6A5EA1E1A8/deb_pass.mp3"
let b = NSURL (string : a )
audioPlayer = AVPlayer ( URL : b! )
}
i don't known why this isn't working.

Comment: i already allowed the NSApp transport Security Setings and Allows Arbitrary loads(true). Just don't play.

Comment: Just add AVKit Player View Controller in storyboard, Initialize player and it will play audio file. If you want to stream audio file from server you need AVPlayer as AVAudioPlayer only works with files.

Comment: Great, If my answer helped you Mark as accepted answer :p.